# Can I get a bit of a string in a console in JS and import it to html?

Tags: javascript, html, oauth

I'm currently building a web based OS with Google 0Auth and I need the users image and some way to import it into html.

The code is [removed]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The code should be HERE, in your question on Stackoverflow, not there, on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have the image URL, so now you can just set the `src` attribute of an `img` tag to that URL.

Example (using your code)

```html
<body>
    <img id="pfp" src="" alt="Not signed in"/> <!-- add an image, can hide until signed in if you'd like -->
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        document.getElementById('pfp').src = profile.getImageUrl(); // this will set the image URL to the URL we received from google
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
      }
    </script>
    <!-- ...more code down here... -->
```

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!